# How to make angular ajax call synchronous?

Tags: angularjs, ajax

```
var SaveIdeaEvaluationForm = function (evaluationForm, ideaId, stageId, isEvaluated) {
            return $http({
                url: SparkApp.FormEvaluation.SaveIdeaEvaluationForm,
                method: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "evaluationForm": evaluationForm,
                    "ideaId": ideaId,
                    "stageId": stageId,
                    "isEvaluated": isEvaluated
                }
            });
        };
```

its asynchronous by default , do we have any property to set as synchronous??

Answer (score 1):

It is widely encouraged to utilise the `$http` service asynchronously. See this approach:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

If for some reason, you cannot do this, utilise the $q library as DrenP suggested.